# Meaning and example of Undefined behaviours related to constant expression in C99

Tags: c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, c99

I don't understand the Undefined Behaviours in C99 related to constant expression.

For example:

> An expression that is required to be an integer constant expression
> does not have an integer type; has operands that are not integer
> constants, enumeration constants, character constants, sizeof
> expressions whose results are integer constants, or immediately-cast
> floating constants; or contains casts (outside operands to sizeof
> operators) other than conversions of arithmetic types to integer types
> (6.6).

I can't find an example of such UB ?

Furthermore I don't understant why a constant expression (evaluated at translation time) does not become an expression evaluated at runtime (instead of being UB).

Comment: Dont' understand the downvote without comment. UBs are always tricky in C, why is this question not legit ?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes either, though you could add the [tag:language-lawyer] tag to questions like this, to clarify that you are interested in the language definition rather than practical use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quoted from the *informative* annex J. To find the actual *normative* text you have to go the section that the appendix J points at, in this case the definition of *integer constant expression* C99 6.6:

> An *integer constant expression*<sup>99)</sup> shall have integer type and shall only have operands
> that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, sizeof
> expressions whose results are integer constants, and floating constants that are the
> immediate operands of casts.

That text is pretty self-explanatory IMO. That is: whenever syntax or normative text elsewhere requires an integer constant expression, whatever you place at such a location must fulfil the above quoted part, or it is not an integer constant expression but undefined behavior. (Violating a "shall" requirement in normative ISO C text is always UB.)

I'd expect compilers to be good at giving errors for this since it's compile-time UB.

For example, this is invalid since an array declaration with static storage duration requires the size to be integer constant expression:

```
int a=1;
static int x [a];
```

Similarly, `int x [1 + 1.0];` would be invalid but `int x[1 + (int)1.0];` is ok.

Comment: Thank you. I had read the section you quoted but didn't find it very self-explanatory. Your examples make it much more clear

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean I think what they are aiming for is that if you write something that isn't an integer constant expression in a place where C expects it, it is UB. The C99 rationale doesn't offer much of an explanation either, just "An integer constant expression must involve only numbers knowable at translation time, and operators with no side effects.".

Comment: @Lundin: The C Standard explicitly allows implementations to accept forms beyond those mandated.  I think what's aimed at isn't constructs that aren't integer constant expressions, but rather those that a particular implementation might treat as an integer constant expression though not required by the Standard.  Some such constructs might plausibly behave usefully in some cases but unpredictably in others, based upon criteria outside the Standard's jurisdiction, so the Standard can't really specify anything meaningful about their behavior without impeding their usefulness.

Comment: @supercat That text in 6.6p10 is most likely not aimed towards _integer_ constant expressions, but rather other forms like floating point, complex numbers, strings etc.

Comment: @Lundin: If an implementation doesn't support floating-point rounding modes, something like `(int)(1.2345 * 1000 + 0.5)` would always be the same [which might be evaluated as either 1234 or 1235].  If it does support rounding modes, however, the value of that expression could depend upon the rounding mode in effect.  I don't think there would have been a consensus in favor of forbidding such an expression as an array dimension on implementations where the value couldn't change, nor in favor of requiring that compilers accept such an expression on platforms with configurable rounding modes.

Answer (score 1):

According to N1570 6.6p10, "An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions."  In general, situations where an implementation would be allowed to reject a program, but would also be allowed to accept it, are classified as Undefined Behavior.  While it might be helpful to specify that an implementation given something like (at file scope):

```
int x,y;
int sz = (uintptr_t)&y - (uintptr_t)&x;
```

would be required to either reject the program, or else behave as though `sz` is initialized to a value matching what would be computed if the indicated conversions and subtraction would be performed at runtime, such constructs would often require linker support, and a compiler may have no way of knowing for certain what constructs the linker would support, or what it would do if code uses an unsupportable construct.

The Standard does not use the term "Undefined Behavior" purely to refer to erroneous constructs, but also applies it to non-portable ones which might be unsupportable or erroneous on some implementations but correct on others.  The authors of the Standard note that Undefined Behavior, among other things, identifies potential areas of "conforming language extension" by allowing implementations to define behaviors beyond those mandated by the Standard.  Viewed in that light, classifying the processing of non-standard forms of integer constant expressions as Undefined Behavior allows compilers to support such constructs when practical and useful, without imposing requirements on the behavior of such constructs that some implementations might be unable to meet.

Returning to the earlier example, a compiler might compute the difference between `&y` and `&x` as the difference between the two objects' offsets within their respective data sections.  Such a computation might only be useful if the objects happened to be defined in the same translation unit, and might yield a meaningless value, without necessarily issuing a diagnostic, if they're not.  A compiler, however, would have no way of knowing whether the objects are defined in the same translation unit, and the Standard would have no concept of code whose behavior would be meaningfully defined if two externally-defined objects are defined in the same compilation unit, but not if they aren't.  The Standard term for behavior that implementations would define in some cases, but not in others, based upon criteria outside the Standard's jurisdiction, is "Undefined Behavior".